# python/regex: match letter only or letter followed by number

Tags: python, regex

I want to split this string 'AB4F2D' in ['A', 'B4', 'F2', 'D'].
Essentially, if character is a letter, return the letter, if character is a number return previous character plus present character (luckily there is no number >9 so there is never a X12).

I have tried several combinations but I am not able to find the correct one:

```
def get_elements(input_string):

    patterns = [
        r'[A-Z][A-Z0-9]',
        r'[A-Z][A-Z0-9]|[A-Z]',
        r'\D|\D\d',
        r'[A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9]',
        r'[A-Z]{1}|[A-Z0-9]{1,2}'
        ]

    for p in patterns:
        elements = re.findall(p, input_string)
        print(elements)
```

results:

```
['AB', 'F2']
['AB', 'F2', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'F', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'F', 'D']
['A', 'B', '4F', '2D']
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\D\d?`

One problem with yours is that you put the shorter alternative first, so the longer one never gets a chance. For example, the correct version of your `\D|\D\d` is `\D\d|\D`. But just use `\D\d?`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Kelly,
```\D\d``` gives 
```['B4', 'F2'] ``` , 
so it's not good,
while 
```\D\d|\D``` 
gives 
```['A', 'B4', 'F2', 'D']``` and could work!

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro Why did you try `\D\d`?

Comment: @MarcoDiGennaro It's not `\D\d`. The trailing question mark is important because it makes the match optional: `\D\d?`

Comment: Just confused... both work! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Use Extended Groups

There is special syntax for python regexes allowing you to match ahead without consuming the characters (and much more).

Here is a pattern I would come up with using that:

```
[A-Z](?![0-9])|[A-Z][0-9]
```

This matches everything in just one pattern. There might be simpler ways to match it, but I find this to be the most flexible if you want to adjust it later. Read it like this: greedily match a letter if the next character is not a digit. If that is not the case, match a letter followed by a digit.

More info in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). If you want to test around I recommend using [a regex tester like this](https://regex101.com/) and make sure to select python syntax.

Comment: On a further note: this does really overshoot your specifications and the other answers give much shorter options. But when working with regexes it is essential to understand its efficiency. Looping through a pattern list is almost always a sign of not utilizing regexes correctly.

Comment: I think their list/looping isn't intended to be a solution. They just do that to show the multiple attempts they've tried.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I first thought they'd try to get matchings for both cases using multiple patterns. Anyway, the solutions `\D\d|\D`, `\D\d?` and `\D(?!\d)|\D\d` should demonstrate how flexible regex matchings are.